# Any way to concat text into mysql row? I need it to save to the db

Tags: php, mysql, database, concatenation

I was running this query, I think its incorrect anyway:

```
"SELECT CONCAT ('VOID: *', notes) FROM invoices WHERE invoiceID = {$rowID}"
```

However, I don't think this fits my needs even if it is correct.  I need to append 'VOID: *' in front of my field.  I don't want to grab the data, and concatenate it, and then re-update.  this seems silly.  Is there a way in mysql to add text to the field without pulling it out first?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the concat function in an update statement like this:

```
"UPDATE invoices SET notes=CONCAT ('VOID: *', notes) WHERE invoiceID = {$rowID}"
```